# Recursive function is not called on every iteration

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement a recursive function in J Query. Instead of returning a series of objects, the recursive function only returns one object, which is the first element of my expected results(which makes me imply that it only do one recursive call).

```
 //recursive function to find every Base Child 
 function GetBaseChild(node)
 {
    if(node.hasOwnProperty("children")){
        for(var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++){
           return GetBaseChild(node.children[i]);
         }
     }else{
        return node;
     }
 }
```

I am assuming that the return in my fall loop, stops my loop from going to the next index and do a recursion call hence the single call. Any idea how I can do it.

**What I have tried**

After that, I added extra logic to test where I am at in my loop and either return the function or not as shown.

```
//recursive function to find every Base Child 
function GetBaseChild(node)
{
    if(node.hasOwnProperty("children")){
        for(var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++){
            if(i < node.children.length -1){
                  GetBaseChild(node.children[i]);
               }else{
                  return GetBaseChild(node.children[i]);
               }
        }
    }else{
        return node;
    }
}
```

Now the function return the last element of my expected results. It should return a series of results. So how can I achieve this.

**Solution**

After browsing the Internet and reading some sources, I realized J Query has some limitations. My problem was being caused by the fact that when I use return then the control breaks out of the loop and the first/last result is returned depending on the logic I had used. And also considering the fact that J Query passes non-primitive types as references I decided to pass an array that my recursive function will manipulate  and use it later in my code. Here is the source code.

```
//recursive function to find every Base Child 
function GetBaseChild(array, node)
{
    if(node.hasOwnProperty("children")){
        for(var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++){
            GetBaseChild(array, node.children[i]);
        }
    }else{
        array.push(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the output the *first* result it should be or the *last* result?

Comment: the output is the first result of a series of results I am expecting.

Comment: What is this meant to recurse through? Elements on the page? A folder?

Comment: I see your updated code, if it's returning the last element that means it is recursing through all of the elements and then only returning the last one. I'm not super familiar with jQuery but it looks like that's what it's written to do

Comment: yep, thats I saw that. In a different language like PHP it will workS as I want it to be because, I recently implemented similar recursive functions and they work okay.